# Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name 'Hello' does not match patterns DialogFlow

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am working on a project with DialogFlow V2 Api using Nodejs and the following code somehow does not seem to work:

```
    var query = req.body.query;
    const request = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        text: {
          text: query,
          languageCode: 'en-US',
        },
      },
      queryParams: {
      contexts: [
          {
            "name": "Question-followup",
            "parameters": {},
            "lifespanCount": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    };

    // Send request and log result
    sessionClient
      .detectIntent(request)
      .then(responses => {
        const result = responses[0].queryResult;
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);   
        if (result.intent) {
          console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`  No intent matchede.`);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
      });
```

And the error I recieve is:

> ERROR: { Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name 'Question-followup' does not
>   match patterns
>   'projects/{projectId=*}/agent/environments/{environmentId=*}/users/{userId=*}/sessions/{sessionId=*}/contexts/{contextId=*},projects/{projectId=*}/agent/sessions/{sessionId=*}/contexts/{contextId=*}'.

Note: I do have "Question-followup" context into an Intent, so it should not be the problem that the context does not exists or something!

Any idea what would this be?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the full path to your context. The Dialogflow v2 Node.js library has a helper method to construct the context path for you.

```
contexts: [
      {
        "name": contextsClient.contextPath(projectId, sessionId, "Question-followup"),
        "parameters": {},
        "lifespanCount": 1
      }
    ]
```